# Which Django/Python handler class will pass logs to the UWSGI logger?

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging, uwsgi

I am running my Django site as a vassal of UWSGI emperor. I have created `/etc/uwsgi-emperor/vassals/mysite.ini` as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/opt/mysite/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 775
chdir = /opt/mysite
master = true
virtualenv = /opt/mysite_virtualenv
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
module = mysite.wsgi:application
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
processes = 1
threads = 1
plugins = python3,logfile
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/mysite.log
vacuum = true
```

But Django logs are not appearing in `file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/mysite.log`.
Which handler class will pass the logs on to UWSGI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `logging.StreamHandler` class. For example, defining LOGGING in `settings.py` as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': None,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```